# adf tree selection listner not working getting error <oracle.adf.view> <RichRenderer> <decodeUnknownKey> <ATTEMPT_SYNC_UNKNOWN_KEY>

Tags: tree, selection, oracle-adf, managed-bean, weblogic12c

I have created a tree in adf programtically. It's showing correctly and I am also able to traverse but when I try clicking on any node, my **selectionListner()** function does not work instead it gives following error on console:

```
 <oracle.adf.view> <RichRenderer> <decodeUnknownKey>   
<ATTEMPT_SYNC_UNKNOWN_KEY>**
```

Following is my code
1) I create an Employee class

```
 package view;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 public class Employee {
 private String name;
 private String location;
 private List<Employee> directs;

 public Employee(String name, String loc){
    this.name = name;
    this.location = loc;
    directs = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  }

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
  public String getLocation() {
    return location;
  }
  public List<Employee> getDirects() {
    return directs;
  }
  public void addDirect(Employee emp){
    directs.add(emp);
  }}
```

2) I created a managed bean with a constructor:

```
List<Employee> allEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
TreeModel employeeTree;

public TestPage_1() {
    super();
    Employee manager1 = new Employee("John","London");
        Employee emp = new Employee("Jack", "London");
        manager1.addDirect(emp);
        emp = new Employee("Ken","New York");
        manager1.addDirect(emp);
        Employee manager2 = new Employee("Ravi","Bangalore");
        emp = new Employee("Ramesh","Bangalore");
        manager2.addDirect(emp);
        Employee manager3 = new Employee("Raju","Pune");
        emp = new Employee("Rakesh","Pune");
        manager3.addDirect(emp);
        manager2.addDirect(manager3);
        emp = new Employee("Jamie","California");

        allEmployees.add(manager1);
        allEmployees.add(manager2);
        allEmployees.add(emp);     

        //Wrapping the list in to a class used by ADF TreeTable.

}

public TreeModel getModel() {
      employeeTree =
          new ChildPropertyTreeModel(allEmployees,"directs");
    return employeeTree;
  }
```

and a selection Listener:

```
public void nodeclicked(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) 
    String adfSelectionListener = "#{backingBeanScope.backing_testPage_1.model.makeCurrent}";

           FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
           Application application = fctx.getApplication();
           ELContext elCtx = fctx.getELContext();
           ExpressionFactory exprFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();
           MethodExpression me = null;
           me =
    exprFactory.createMethodExpression(elCtx, adfSelectionListener, Object.class, new Class[] { SelectionEvent.class });
           me.invoke(elCtx, new Object[] { selectionEvent });

           RichTree tree = (RichTree)selectionEvent.getSource();
           TreeModel model = (TreeModel)tree.getValue();
           //get selected nodes
           RowKeySet rowKeySet = selectionEvent.getAddedSet();
           Iterator rksIterator = rowKeySet.iterator();
           while (rksIterator.hasNext()) {
               List key = (List)rksIterator.next();
               JUCtrlHierBinding treeBinding = null;
               treeBinding = (JUCtrlHierBinding)((CollectionModel)tree.getValue()).getWrappedData();
               JUCtrlHierNodeBinding nodeBinding = treeBinding.findNodeByKeyPath(key);
               Row rw = nodeBinding.getRow();
               System.out.println("row: " + rw.getAttribute(0)); // You can get any attribute
               System.out.println("View Object name---->" + nodeBinding.getViewObject().getName());

           }
    }
```

and my tree UI is:

```
<af:tree id="testPage_tree" var="node" value="#{backingBeanScope.backing_testPage_1.model}"
                         binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_testPage_1.testPage_tree}"
                         selectionListener="#{backingBeanScope.backing_testPage_1.nodeclicked}">
                    <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
                        <af:outputLabel value="#{node.name}" id="ol1"
                                        binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_testPage_1.ol1}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </af:tree>
```

I am trying to find out which node in tree is selected but my breakpoints do not work in selection listener function.

Comment: <oracle.adf.view> <RichRenderer> <decodeUnknownKey> <ATTEMPT_SYNC_UNKNOWN_KEY> this is the error i am getting on console, think its my EL thats not correct  but even a simple breakpoint is hit in my listener func.

Comment: this error comes on the very start when i try clicking on tree to dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to set `rowSelection` property of tree component

Comment: since you have not specified if the tree is selectable, you can not select any node (node does not grayed out on clicking) and therefore selection listener is not invoked. Set rowSelection="single", this will allow you to select a single node at a time. The error you are mentioning may be just a warning.

Comment: i've got one more query regarding selection listner, for all the tuts i searched on net they all use arraylist for populating the tree but in tree selection listner tuts i see JUCtrlHierBinding in this same code of selection listner i am using          treeBinding = (JUCtrlHierBinding)
         ((CollectionModel)tree1.getValue()).getWrappedData(); but it gives error java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding.... i dnt knw what type casting should i doo fr this.. statment,

Comment: I would also suggest you to ask a new question for the error you are getting, someone else may have faced the same issue before