# error java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding in adf tree selection listener

Tags: oracle, arraylist, tree, selection, oracle-adf

While working on adf tree selection listener I am facing problem of casting arraylist to UCtrlHierBinding.

I am populating my tree using POJO's. My code is on this link.
[adf tree - selection listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125809/adf-tree-selection-listner-not-working-getting-error-oracle-adf-view-richrend/28133896#28133896)

In selection listener I get the following error:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found:
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.
    model.ChildPropertyTreeModel@9f8a597.
    makeCurrent(org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.SelectionEvent)
```

at stmt
`me.invoke(elCtx, new Object[] { selectionEvent });`

and, even if I comment this statement then I get another one at, that I am more concerned about as I need to access the node value.

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding
```

at stmt
`treeBinding = (JUCtrlHierBinding)((CollectionModel)tree.getValue()).getWrappedData();`

Comment: please suggest me for "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding", thanks in advance

Comment: thanks CSchulz for proper edits...:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you have implemented the tree to get rid of the exception.
To start with, change your Employee class as below

```
 public class Employee {
 private String name;
 private String location;
 private List<Employee> directs;

 public Employee(String name, String loc, List<Employee> directs){
    this.name = name;
    this.location = loc;
    this.directs =  directs;
  }
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
  public String getLocation() {
    return location;
  }
  public List<Employee> getDirects() {
    return directs;
  }
}
```

Then create an EmployeeBean class:

```
public class EmployeeBean {
    private List<Employee> allEmployees;
    public EmployeeBean() {
        super();
    }
    public void setAllEmployees(List<Employee> allEmployees) {
        this.allEmployees = allEmployees;
    }
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        List<Employee> directList = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
        directList.add(new Employee("Ken", "New York", new ArrayList<Employee>()));
        Employee manager1 = new Employee("John", "London", directList);
        directList= new ArrayList<Employee>();
        directList.add(new Employee("Ramesh", "London", new ArrayList<Employee>()));
        Employee manager2 = new Employee("Ravi", "Bangalore",directList);
        directList= new ArrayList<Employee>();
        directList.add(new Employee("Rakesh", "Pune", new ArrayList<Employee>()));
        Employee manager3 = new Employee("Raju", "Pune",  directList);

        allEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        allEmployees.add(manager1);
        allEmployees.add(manager2);
        allEmployees.add(manager3);
        return allEmployees;
    }
}
```

Righr click on EmployeeBean class and select 'Create Data Control'. This will create an EmployeeBean data control that can be used to create tree component on the page

Drag and drop allEmployees from EmployeeBean on to the page as a tree component. Now your selection listener code will work without any errors.
For more details refer http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/38-pojo-editable-tree-169180.pdf